# How to avoid downcasting of abstract class to child class?

Tags: java, android, abstract-class, self-type

I have the following structure in my android app:

```
    abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
        protected BaseViewModel mViewModel;
    }
```

```
    abstract class BaseViewModel extends ViewModel { ... }
```

```
    class MainActivityViewModel extends BaseViewModel { ... }
```

```
    class MainActivity extends BaseActivity{ ... }
```

now when initializing the BaseViewModel in the MainActivity i want to enter the type as a generic so i dont have to cast it everytime into the child implmenentation `((MainActivityViewModel)mViewModel)`, i've read about generic self-typing, but dont understand how this works in this exact scenario.

Comment: Why not give `BaseActivity` a type parameter which has to be a child of `BaseViewModel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `protected BaseViewModel mViewModel;` to have a generic type, you should
rewrite you class as follow:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity<T> extends AppCompatActivity{
        protected T mViewModel;
    }

 public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity<MainActivityViewModel >{ ... }
```

I hope I answered you question. If I don't, Should you explain a bit more?